# Core Text newline character artifact with custom font

Tags: ios, iphone, core-text, uifont, custom-font

When I draw NSAttributedString in UILabel when there is a custom font involved, quote character is inserted with each newline ('\n') character.

This issue does not appear with standard / build-in iOS fonts, yet it is enough to have just 1 character with custom one and bum...

Tested with multiple custom fonts, iOS6 and iOS7 so it is not just 'this one custom font' issue.

**Example with built-in fonts only - everything OK:**

[image]

**But just style any part of the text with custom font - and here we go:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have to tried with different custom font?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with multiple fonts, at least 5 or 6. I added new screenshots

Comment: Could you show some code? With hardcoded test string values, does it still does it?